# Can we set Guest User Sharing Settings for Account Contact Relationships?

Tags: relationships, guest-user

Also called "Contacts to Multiple Accounts".

If I set Sharing Settings for Accounts, does that automatically cascade down to Account Contact Relationships?

Thanks for your help,
Baird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AccountContactRelation record inherits its visibility from its two parent objects, so you can't set sharing. If people can see the Account and the Contact, then they can see the child.

So you must have access to both the Account and the Contact, and then you'll see it.

Comment: Thanks David.  That's what I suspected.  I'm currently refactoring to move from AccountContactRoles to AccountContactRelationships so I'll report back on what I find.